# Android show dialog in Custom View

Tags: dialog, android-custom-view

I create a custom view which showing the simple game

I set the custom view in the MainActivity

```
setContentView(new CustomView())
```

In this custom view, only have few ball and the timer

When a ball touch another ball. The timer will stop and show the result.

I don't know how to show the result in a better way. So i tried to create a dialog to show the result.

This code is write in the CustomView class

```
if (ballIsTouch) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Result");
            alertDialog.setMessage(point);
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

However, the page is freezed. The dialog haven't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- create() - is a final step -when you use builder pattern to create dialog u first set in chain all variables and then create dialog - and show so it should be

  ```
      AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
      alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Result");
      alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(point);
      alertDialogBuilder.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  dialog.dismiss();
              }
          });
      AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
      alertDialog.show();
  ```

or

```
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Result")
          .setMessage(point)
          .setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

ensure you getContext() is valid (should be activity, service context)**
in activity use **this** or **Myactivity.this** in interface/callback in fragment **getActivity()**

> **see [Dialog creation context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577987/how-to-show-dialog-box-from-the-class-which-extends-application-in-android/29724324#29724324)