# How to use OneSignal in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, onesignal

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.volleybd.tsp.onesignalfuck">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

    <application
        android:name=".Tapplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my Application file:

```
public class Tapplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new NotificationOpenedHandler())
                .init();
    }

    // This fires when a notificaiton is opened by tapping on it or one is received while the app is runnning.
    private class NotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(String message, JSONObject additionalData, boolean isActive) {
            try {
                String messageTitle;
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = null;

                if (additionalData != null) {
                    if (additionalData.has("discount"))
                        messageTitle = "Discount!";
                    else if (additionalData.has("bonusCredits"))
                        messageTitle = "Bonus Credits!";
                    else
                        messageTitle = "Other Extra Data";

                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setTitle(messageTitle)
                            .setMessage(message + "\n\n" + additionalData.toString());
                }
                else if (isActive) // If a push notification is received when the app is being used it does not display in the notification bar so display in the app.
                    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setTitle("OneSignal Message")
                            .setMessage(message);

                // Add your app logic around this so the user is not interrupted during gameplay.
                if (builder != null)
                    builder.setCancelable(true)
                            .setPositiveButton("OK",null)
                            .create().show();

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i click one push notification I get below is LogCat log:

```
01-23 02:15:41.318 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
01-23 02:15:41.318 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:571)
01-23 02:15:41.318 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:310)
01-23 02:15:41.318 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
01-23 02:15:41.329 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
01-23 02:15:41.329 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal.Tapplication$ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler.notificationOpened(Tapplication.java:51)
01-23 02:15:41.329 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at com.onesignal.OneSignal.fireNotificationOpenedHandler(OneSignal.java:891)
01-23 02:15:41.329 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at com.onesignal.OneSignal.runNotificationOpenedCallback(OneSignal.java:886)
01-23 02:15:41.329 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at com.onesignal.OneSignal.handleNotificationOpened(OneSignal.java:914)
01-23 02:15:41.329 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedProcessor.processIntent(NotificationOpenedProcessor.java:88)
01-23 02:15:41.329 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedProcessor.processFromActivity(NotificationOpenedProcessor.java:52)
01-23 02:15:41.329 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedReceiver.onReceive(NotificationOpenedReceiver.java:11)
01-23 02:15:41.329 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2725)
01-23 02:15:41.329 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
01-23 02:15:41.329 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
01-23 02:15:41.329 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-23 02:15:41.329 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-23 02:15:41.330 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-23 02:15:41.330 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-23 02:15:41.330 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-23 02:15:41.330 19727-19727/com.volleybd.tsp.onesignal W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

As I am in application file I can't do  activity.this . 
please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29724324/5483217) should apply to your situation. Especially the following part:

> u can use application context to create dialog by adding before call
>   to Dialog.show();
>
> `Dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);`

So in your case:

```
Dialog dialog = builder.setCancelable(true).setPositiveButton("OK",null).create();
dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
dialog.show();
```