# Permission error is still showing even when added permission in manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-alertdialog, android-permissions

I implemented `AlertDialog` in my class which extend Application class, also added proper permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

See my code:

```
private void showAlertDialog(Context context) {
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // do some stuff eg: context.onCreate(super)
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setMessage("Messag...")
        .setTitle("Title")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", listener);

        Dialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        dialog.show();
}
```

Call Method:

```
showAlertDialog(getApplicationContext());
```

I tried this answer, it was working yesterday, now is not working: [How to show Dialog Box from the class which extends Application in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577987/how-to-show-dialog-box-from-the-class-which-extends-application-in-android/29724324#29724324)

BTW, it was working yesterday, I don't know why it is not working today, what am I missing?

Comment: why alert dialog in application class?

Comment: @AmitJangid because whenever my app goes from background to foreground, I want user to enter 4 digit paascode.

Comment: Please post the error. *Permission error is still showing even when added permission in manifest* doesn't clear anything.

Comment: @PoojaSingh Which is the API you are using? (your phone)

Comment: @BachVu I'm testing on Nougat 7.0

Comment: @Rohit5k2 Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@559c4d6 -- permission denied for window type 2003

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit Exactly, I tried that only, and it was working fine, but now it is not working.

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/36101111/5148289 also check other answers. they might help you out.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW If the app targets API level 23 or higher, the app user must explicitly grant this permission to the app through a permission management screen

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit TYPE.TOAST is working for Nougat, will it work for all devices from APi 17 to 27?

Comment: @PoojaSingh i am not sure.. what you can do is make condition.. like for above API level 23 you use `TYPE.TOAST` and for below `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`. but make sure to check if `TYPE.TOAST` is working for all.. if it is cheers

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit I haven't put the condition, I just changed to TYPE.TOAST and everything works fine except Oreo version. Now what should I do?

Comment: @PoojaSingh same error in oreo? check if `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` works for you.

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY: Two Problem: permission error below Oreo , 2) Dialog box is itself not showing in Oreo. So no use?

Comment: @PoojaSingh for your first problem you can apply condition that for only OREO it will use `TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY` for other versions it will use `TYPE.TOAST`. i hope doing this your second problem will automatically get solved.

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit TYPE_APP_OVR...is also not working for Oreo, ofcourse app is not crashing, but alert dialog is also not calling. And how can I add permission in my non-activity class for blow/high version if/else condition?

Comment: @PoojaSingh have you tried `TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL`?

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit Not working in both version

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit I'm trying this: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
        } else {
            dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);
        }  Any Idea?

Comment: if `TYPE_TOAST` is working in 7.0 check with this `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26`

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit I tried this & app is not CRASHING in all version:if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
            dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
        } else {
            dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);
        }--------------------Now, our problem is TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY is not giving any effect on Oreo version. For that what can we do?

Comment: let me test in on my side an will come back to you after i find any solution. :)

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit Sure

Answer (score -1):

Did you define runtime permissions if you are checking in marshmallow or above API level devices?

Check the overlay permission

```
public static int OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 1234;

public void someMethod() {
if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
            Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
    startActivityForResult(intent, OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
}}
```

In onActivityResult,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            // SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission not granted...
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally----**

Check if the device has API 23+

if 23+ API then check if the user has permission or not

if had permit once don't drive him to `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` and if has not to permit yet then ask for runtime permission check

Put below the line in your `onCreate()` method. Put this after `setContentView()`

```
checkPermission();
```

Now put below code in onActivityResult,

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            // You don't have permission
            checkPermission();
        } else {
            // Do as per your logic 
        }
    }
}
```

Now finally the checkPermission method code,

```
public void checkPermission() {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}}
```

And declare a variable as global

```
public static int ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 5469;
```

**Happy Coding :)**

Comment: May be at that time permission is already allowed for that application. Go to settings-->Application Management--->Choose your app---->Then go to permissions sections--->Allow Permission
Check it is allowed or not

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer!

Comment: i guess `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` isn't dangerous permission. no need to check at runtime.

Comment: Settings -> Apps -> Gear icon in the top bar -> Draw over other apps (under the Advanced section)

Comment: @Swati Please suggest

Comment: @PoojaSingh Plz check my edited answer after finally--

Comment: @Swati I'm getting this error for Oreo version otherwise works fine: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: @Swati I haven't put your code, I just changed to TYPE.TOAST and everything works fine except Oreo version. Now I want to show passcode for All Activity from my class which extends Application class. Where should I put the code? All Activities or my class?

Comment: I have no idea about TYPE.TOAST
Please take help from @V-rundPuro-hit

If I'll find will let you know :)

Comment: @Swati  I'm trying this: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) { dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY); } else { dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST); } Any Idea? –

Comment: @Swati  I tried this & app is not CRASHING in all version:if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) { dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY); } else { dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST); }--------------------Now, our problem is TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY is not giving any effect on Oreo version. For that what can we do?