# Oreo version, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY not crashing, but no effect

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

See:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
    dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
} else {
    dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);
}
```

Above code is not crashing my app, but there is no effect for my Oreo 27 8.0.1 version.

See method in my Non-Activity class:

```
private void showAlertDialog(final Context context) {
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", listener);

    View view = inflater
        .inflate(R.layout.row_passcode_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(view);

    Dialog dialog = builder.create();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27) {
        dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
    } else {
        dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST);
    }

    dialog.show();

}
```

Also check: [Permission error is still showing even when added permission in manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54823334/permission-error-is-still-showing-even-when-added-permission-in-manifest)

Comment: What error it says in logcat?

Comment: @Piyush No error, but no effect, not showing dialog box

Comment: @PoojaSingh did you check it >https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208897/android-permission-denied-for-window-type-2038-using-type-application-overlay

Comment: @AD10 Hi, I already differentiate the version, problem is TYPE.TOAST is working fine till Nougat, and TYPE OVERLAY is not giving effect/working on Oreo.

Comment: okay it means there is permission problem, you need to fire intent for it like this >>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437721/how-to-give-screen-overlay-permission-on-my-activity

Comment: check the answer of @Ahmad Shahwaiz

Comment: If the app targets API level 23 or higher, the app user must explicitly grant this permission to the app through a permission management screen. The app requests the user's approval by sending an intent with action ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION. The app can check whether it has this authorization by calling Settings.canDrawOverlays()